# Odata Query Filter for bool value inside a Array?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata, asp.net-core-6.0

I have below data that need to be filtered using Odata.

```
[
    {
        "name":"abc",
        "class":1,
        "subject":[
            {
                "name":"Math",
                "IsIntrested":true
            },
            {
                "name":"Chem",
                "IsIntrested":false
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

From the Student array, need to filter the subject that student is interested, i.e., the output should have only the interested subject for student.

Using this Query filter

```
https://localhost:7014/api/base?$filter=subject/any(a:a/IsIntrested eq true)
```

But still it returns the false record. What i am missing here?

expected output

```
[
    {
        "name":"abc",
        "class":1,
        "subject":[
            {
                "name":"Math",
                "IsIntrested":true
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Update-1**
Controller Code:-

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll(OdataQueryOption Odata)
{
    var Students = await mediator.Send(new GetAllStudents { Odata});
    return Ok(Students);
}
```

Was facing some issue with `$Select, $expand` post suggestion from *Vladimir*.

Issue fix was, in the repository layer the return type need to be dynamic instead of typeof(edm class).

```
public async Task<IQueryable<dynamic>> GetStudents(odataqueryoption op)
        {
        var result = Student
                       .Include(_ => _.Subjects)
                       .AsNoTracking();

         return op.applyTo(result);
        }
```

But after all these, getting below issue

```
Could not find a property named 'subjects' on type 'Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.Expressions.SelectAllAndExpand_1OStudents'
```

Comment: Does `https://localhost:7014/api/base?$filter=subject/any(a:a/IsIntrested eq 1)` return the expected result?

Comment: No, it returns all subjects. i need only where IsIntrested=true.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are filtering top level list, but you need to filter inner list (subjects), for this you can use:

```
https://localhost:7014/api/base?$select=name,class,subject($filter=IsIntrested eq true)
```

Comment: Getting the error "It's not allowed to nest query options within 'subject' selection". Previously i was using Non-EDM approach , but still with EDM same issue.

Comment: Any chance `https://localhost:7014/api/base?$select=name,class&$expand=subject($filter=IsIntrested eq true)` will work?

Comment: Not sure,  but in my case i am using OData Query Option, there $select & $expand both doesn't return any data. so getting Null data getting. even $select =Id is also failing.

Comment: do you have example of controller code you using?

Comment: Updated in the Question. $select,$expand issue resolved after making the return type as dynamic. Was using AutoMapper, but post making Dynamic, it was complex to handle, so removed, & the service layer returns iQueryable.

Comment: I'd start with `[EnableQuery]` attribute on controller method.

Comment: In my case, i want to metalize the data before reaching to Controller. I.e, when i join student & subject tables i have a lot more columns that i suppose to show as a response. So i had to fetch the data with Tolist(), then  i need to use Automapper/ Linq2Sql to prepare the data. so OdataQueryOption is the suggested one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249063/discussion-between-lokanath-das-and-vladimir).